# Closing Tab in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have a function called in popup.html that creates a tab, inserts a mailto to trigger a local (or gmail) mail event. It's my desire for it to then close itself. I've tried numerous things, but it seems like I need something that does the equivalent of:

```
tabId = chrome.tabs.query(I DON'T KNOW!);
chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
```

here's the current code:

```
var query = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
function callback(tabs) {
    var currentTab = tabs[0];
    console.log(currentTab);
}
chrome.tabs.remove(chrome.tabs.query(query, callback));
```

but it's not working.

if useful, here's how I create the tab (which does work as desired):

```
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        getTabs(tabs, function(full_mail_link){
          chrome.tabs.create({ url: full_mail_link });
        });
    });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Close iself = close the popup? Close the tab you opened? Both?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know what your getTabs function does. Yet if you know how to find the tab id of the tab you want all you need to do is

```
chrome.tabs.remove(tabId, optionalCallback);
```

Comment: thanks - problem is I can't figure out how to get the tabId in the first place... any tips?

Comment: of the current: `chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){ tabId = tabs[0].id //tabs is an array of tabs})

Answer (score 5):

this must be work:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
 });
```

Comment: `getSelected` is deprecated. [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-getSelected](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-getSelected). You'll need to use `chrome.tabs.query()` - See Edwin's comment to his answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
//create the tab
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    getTabs(tabs, function(full_mail_link){
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: full_mail_link }, callBackOnCreate);
    });
});

function callBackOnCreate(tab)
{
     globalCreatedTab = tab.id;
}

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function(tabs) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i)
      {
          if (tabs[i].id === globalCreatedTab)
          {
              chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id, [optional callback]);
          }
      }

 });
```

Solution: use the query function with the callback and execute the remove function in the callback.

It looks like normal `window.open` and `window.close()` should also work,
The tab-id is an integer or an array containing integers.

Comment: thanks but according to google getSelected is deprecated and we're supposed to use query now...

Comment: Why are you selecting the first one in the active tabs array? (hint: this is a hint your code is not robust)

Comment: What I mean is, your code will work strangely if there's more than one window open.

Comment: The OP wanted to now why his code isn't working. the remove code needs to be inside the query callback. If you want the array of tabs with ID. Of course you can do additional coding to check if the tab is the tab you've created. Will update.

Comment: @Mouser thanks - sorry to pester but do you have an example of how that loop array might work?